# 2 return formats for ACF Time & Date Picker

Tags: datetime, time, advanced-custom-fields

I have a site build with several different variations of time and date throughout the site as well as a format needed for outputting to a calendar export file for Gmail/Outlook/iCal. I'd like to only use one field, the combo date and time picker, but I can't get it to work for all the custom formats. Is there any way to have more than one return format?

If I could have a `Ymd` and a `Y/m/d H:i` that would cover everything.